# Node.js server app using cors, express and google api not working after azure deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, express, google-api, cors

I have a node.js server api app that is not working after being deployed to azure.

It initially relies on google.api to get the data and after that stores the data in an array and sends it to client by responding to express get calls.

Initially I used:

```
const express = require('express');  
const app = express();  
const cors = require("cors");
const _ = require("lodash");
const port = 30000;

app.use(cors());
```

which worked well enough on localhost.

For deployment, after following a tutorial I changed that to:

```
const express = require('express');  
const app = express();  
const cors = require("cors");
const _ = require("lodash");
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var http = require('http');

app.use(cors());

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function () { 
});
```

which did not work and finally:

```
const express = require('express');  
const app = express(); 
const _ = require("lodash");
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

var login = require('./routes/login');
...
app.use('/login', login);
...
module.exports = app;
```

and created a new folder for the get commands, as is done here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/blob/master/app.js.

Nothing seems to work and I continue to get the error:

> GET http://nameofsite/login 404 (Not Found)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load nameofsite/login. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'nameofclient' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 404.

I have tried including the cors header as well as adding the client site to cors allowed origins in the azure portal but it makes no difference. Can anyone help with this issue or provide info on how to correctly format a node.js server using info from a google sheets document?

Comment: I dont know your specific problem, but since you are using node.js , i would suggest you to use a designated API package (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet), instead of some CORS magic. But for me it seems more like a header problem. For testing purposes i'd suggest you to try this: 
`app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});`

Comment: try to install cors chorme extension if its work then do change at code level https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Zsolt, I am using google api (var google = require('googleapis'); etc.) to handle communication with the google spreadsheet. I tried adding the app.use.. you suggested but it gave the same result. Should I perhaps add it to every express call?

Comment: @Adiii I added the chrome extension and then the cors kicked in, many thanks for that, however, I still get the error `GET http://server-api-url/login 404 (Not Found)` which render my api unusable and hinders me from accessing the data.

Comment: Are you pushing the node_modules folder up to Azure?

Comment: @Stephen yes I am.

Comment: Have you tried using `*` for "ALLOWED ORIGINS"?

Comment: you welcome and i will recomend to make your server like this const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly question but when you moved the VM to Azure did you setup your ip address, update your external DNS and configure the virtual network to allow the correct traffic that Node and your code needs?